# How to fix "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: chrome not reachable" in WSL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use WSL2 to rails application and had this error when RSpec is running:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
              chrome not reachable
                (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.75)
```

Someone know to fix it?

My capybara.rb:

```
require "capybara/rails"
require "selenium-webdriver"

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[headless no-sandbox]
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: true }
```

I put the path in env variables to reach my chromewebdriver binary, following this article "https://ngauthier.com/2017/09/rails-system-tests-with-headless-chrome-on-windows-bash-wsl.html" and nothing!

Comment: How are you initializing the web driver? Does this happen every time the web driver is initialized or intermittently?

Comment: This happen every time, i run the tests, and when it reachs the views tests with capybara, this happens!

I put my capybara.rb above, but my problem is basic make works tests in capybara using chromedriver in WSL

Comment: Can you post the code for one of the tests that is failing?

Comment: @GregBurghardt This error just happen in view tests, I find out in other forums this happens because the WSL try to use in background chrome but wsl dont have a "display" and this make all view tests fail with that error:

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
              chrome not reachable
                (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.75)

The tests are okay using linux environment, but in WSL2 dont work, and a cant fix this problem with chromedriver within WSL2

Answer (score 0):

I just fix it with the following code

```
 Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
        options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[
          headless no-sandbox disable-gpu window-size=1920x1080
        ])
          Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
            browser: :chrome,
            desired_capabilities: {
              "chromeOptions" => {
                w3c: false
              }
            }
          )
      end
```

Please let me know if this is resolve your issue